# How to turn my data into a ROC curve in R?

Tags: r, roc

I'd like to generate ROC curves in R, but I'm confused about what input to give either ROCR or pROC.

I have 5000 data-points for which I know the true classification (1 or 0), and a continuous prediction score for each.

Should I use the 5000 classifications and prediction scores as input? Or am I supposed to manually apply a cutoff to the predictions to turn them into binary predictors? Do I have to do that for multiple cutoff thresholds and supply them all to the `roc` function(s), or is it all done for me?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R.

Comment: [A simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=r+rocr&oq=r+rocr&gs_l=serp.3..0l9.1011585.1015114.0.1016001.8.7.1.0.0.0.111.485.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.54.serp..1.7.487.QUWqqH5iD78) for "r rocr" yields [this tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/an-example-of-roc-curves-plotting-with-rocr/). [Another simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=r+proc&oq=r+proc&gs_l=serp.3..0i67j0l9.151907.153260.0.153563.4.4.0.0.0.0.185.414.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.54.serp..0.4.410.I3bNRma-IqE) for "r proc" yields [this](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/12/77).

Answer (score 1):

The ROC curve relates the false positive rate -- #FP/(#FP + #TN) to the true positive rate -- #TP/(#TP + FN).  For the ROC curve, the false positive rate is on the x-axis, and the true positive rate is on the y-axis.

As you said, one way to do this would be to calculate the above quantities for many values of your threshold, and plot these values against each other.

Alternatively, you could use the [ROCR](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/ROCR.pdf) package or the [pROC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/pROC.pdf) package, which I personally find easier to use.

Good luck!

Comment: So if you use one of the packages and ask the right way, it is all done for you

Answer (score 0):

Both packages will take your prediction scores for the 5000 points, as well as the true classification for those 5000 points. They will do so in a slightly different manner, so read their respective manuals to figure out how to call them.